# Confirm box not working

Tags: php, javascript, parsing

```
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick=show_confirm(http://mydomain.com/delete.php)>
```

I have this button and this JavaScript function, but they don't work.
When I click the button, nothing happens.
What is wrong with my code?

```
function show_confirm(url){
   var r = confirm("Do you want to delete this?");
   if (r == true){
       window.navigate(url);
      }
   else{
       alert("You pressed Cancel.");
       }
 }
```

Comment: As an aside, you don't need to check if `r==true` - by putting an expression inside an `if` statement, you're always checking whether it is true. Just use `if (r)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="show_confirm('http://mydomain.com/delete.php')">
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass the url inside double quotes.

```
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick=show_confirm("http://mydomain.com/delete.php")>
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/93QWJ/

Answer (score 3):

Your html is not well formed.

```
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick=show_confirm(http://mydomain.com/delete.php)>
```

should be

```
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="javascript:show_confirm('http://mydomain.com/delete.php');" />
```

The `javascript:` is only necessary if you also have VBScript on the page, but it's a good habit to be in.

Answer (score 1):

no quotes around onclick function
like this : "show_confirm(url)"